# Can't import number from html site code

Tags: java, html, selenium

So I wanted to get number from the site with following code. What I want is to import number "Pieniądze"(21762) and replace " " and "PLN" so it will be number but my code posted below doesn't work. Any suggestions where is the mistake in that parsing?

```
 int money;
 money=Integer.parseInt((driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[1]"))).getText().replace(" ", "").replace("PLN", ""));
```

[image: Html of what I want]

> run:
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129) on port 24400
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3Re.png)/div/div[5]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3Re.png)" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
>     (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.89)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Myszsoda', ip: '192.168.1.15', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129), userDataDir=C:\Users\Soda\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6316_26092}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=53.0.2785.89, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: 1627abc13cd518cda22e084f22304b80
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3Re.png)/div/div[5]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH3Re.png)}
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:683)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:377)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:506)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:369)
>       at dunnoyet.DunnoYet.main(DunnoYet.java:132)
>   C:\Users\Soda\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 20 seconds)

Comment: "doesn't work" really doesn't tell us a lot. It would also help if you'd provide a [mcve], with the minimal HTML required to reproduce the problem *as text* (along with the code, of course).

Comment: Here is the error

Comment: You haven't addressed any other aspect of my request though. The error does seem pretty self-explanatory, mind you: you called `findElement` and then gave it an XPath expression that doesn't select an element...

Comment: What I "hate" is poor questions - Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers. That means putting time into asking a good question, making it as minimal as possible, etc. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xpath` returns `String`, not `WebElement`. Remove `/text()[1]` from the `xpath` or the `getText()` method from the result.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).replace(" ", "")...
```

Comment: It fixes the problem partly, now problem is, could you help getting the number from middle?        


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Pieniądze
13062
+5070/h"

Comment: @Myszsoda: That's a second question, and should be presented as a separate post *after* you've researched it properly.

Comment: @Myszsoda I take it the problem is resolved? you can always split the result by `" "` and take the result by index.